# Excluding blank rows in CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new to using CTE queries in SQL Server. I've built this query with help from the web in an effort to start building my "change log" to highlight changes made in my database. Please see example linked below. I'd like to exclude rows where there are no changes. Can you assist in how to accomplish this?

Row #3 with Nov 7 changedate has blank values. I would like for this row to not display. I also don't want to have to do something like WHERE row1 <> '' AND row2 <> '' AND row3 <> '', etc, because my final query will contain much much more rows. Is this possible?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/134bd/4/0

Comment: You do it with a WHERE clause at the end of your query, checking each CASE statement to see if it is blank or null (depending on the column).

Comment: @TabAlleman thank you, but that is what I was trying to avoid. Is there no other way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that you can use.
Below uses COALESCE function.

Using the same data and just modified your code from sqlfiddle.
The `CASE` statement to return `NULL` when match and cast data types to varchar, then use `COALESCE` in the where

Below modified script to include nTEXT column. You can use `DATALENGTH` with `COALESCE` in the `WHERE` clause.

**Modified:**

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmp
([memid] int, [empid] int, [name] varchar(50),[salary] int,  [room] varchar(50), changedate datetime, ntxt ntext);

INSERT INTO tblEmp
    ([memid], [empid], [name], [salary], [room], [changedate], [ntxt])
VALUES
(41, 1, 'peter', 1000, 'Regency', '11/4/2012', ''),
(43, 1, 'peterz', 2000, 'Regency','11/5/2013', 'nn') ,
(44, 1, 'peterz', 2000, 'Regency','11/7/2013', '') ,
(45, 4, 'sally', 2001, 'Sheratio','11/2/2013', '') ,
(46, 4, 'sally', 2000, 'Sheraton','11/6/2013', ''),
(47, 1, 'peter', 3000, 'Regency','12/4/2013', '') ,
(48, 4, 'sallye', 2000,'Sheraton 1', '11/9/2013', '') ,
(49, 4, 'sally', 3000, 'Sheraton','11/6/2013', 'kljslkdjflkajslkjasdlkjalskjdlakjsdlkjasldjfk')
;

 WITH cte  AS 
(
  SELECT   
          empid,
         name,
         salary, room,
          changedate,
          ntxt,
         rn=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY changedate)
  FROM   tblemp
) 
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c1.empid, oldname=CASE WHEN c1.Name=c2.Name THEN NULL ELSE C1.Name END,
           newname=CASE WHEN c1.Name=c2.Name THEN NULL ELSE C2.Name END,
           oldsalary=CASE WHEN c1.salary=c2.salary THEN NULL ELSE C1.salary END,
           newsalary=CASE WHEN c1.salary=c2.salary THEN NULL ELSE C2.salary END, 
    oldroom=CASE WHEN c1.Room=c2.Room THEN NULL ELSE C1.Room END,
           newroom=CASE WHEN c1.room=c2.room THEN NULL ELSE C2.room END,
    c2.changedate
    , c2.ntxt
    FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte c2 
    ON c1.empid=c2.empid AND c2.RN=c1.RN+1 
) x
WHERE NOT (COALESCE(oldname, newname, CAST(oldsalary AS VARCHAR), CAST(newsalary AS VARCHAR), CAST(oldroom AS VARCHAR), CAST(newroom AS VARCHAR)) is null
    AND DATALENGTH(ntxt) = 0)
ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```

Comment: that query returns one row of null values

Comment: Modified. Should be "is `not` null" for your requirement

Comment: It would work if OP only wanted to check for NULL, but he needs to check for blank spaces in some columns.

Comment: @TabAlleman .. As I mentioned that the OP needs to change the `CASE` to return `NULL` instead of blank to use `COALESCE` function. Please check the modified code I posted

Comment: I just found out that some of the columns are going to be in NTEXT format. Is there any way to compare these NTEXT fields like the rest?

Comment: @trevoray .. Modified to include one `nText` column with your sample data and script to check `nText` column using `DATALENGTH` to check if the length is zero.

Comment: @t_m This looks promising! But, I can't get the Build Schema to work in sql fiddle. I get this error with your code: Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.:

Comment: @trevoray.. I think sqlfiddle site is currently not working. I tried `CREATE TABLE tblEmp ([memid] int)  insert into tblEmp(memid) select 1` and it still gave the same error message as you.

Comment: tks! I got it working using your original example and just changing my datafields to Varchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach with SQL Server 2012 would be to use `LAG` in the common table expression to be able to detect row by row changes. The CTE basically pulls out each row along with the relevant data from the previous row, and does a straight forward compare in the outer query to generate the result.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    empid, changeDate,
    LAG(name)   OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY changeDate) oldname,   name,
    LAG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY changeDate) oldsalary, salary,
    LAG(room)   OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY changeDate) oldroom,   room
  FROM tblEmp
)
SELECT empid,
  CASE WHEN name<>oldname     THEN oldname   ELSE '' END oldname, 
  CASE WHEN name<>oldname     THEN name      ELSE '' END newname, 
  CASE WHEN salary<>oldsalary THEN oldsalary ELSE '' END oldsalary, 
  CASE WHEN salary<>oldsalary THEN salary    ELSE '' END newsalary, 
  CASE WHEN room<>oldroom     THEN oldroom   ELSE '' END oldroom, 
  CASE WHEN room<>oldroom     THEN room      ELSE '' END newroom,
  changeDate
FROM cte
WHERE oldname<>name OR oldsalary<>salary OR oldroom<>room
ORDER BY empid, changeDate;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c0f6/1).

Comment: I just found out that some of the columns are going to be in NTEXT format. Is there any way to compare these NTEXT fields like the rest?